# Idiomatic and functional JS reduction of array of objects with predicate

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, reduction

From an array of objects representing stocks, their spot prices and other properties such as

```
stocks = [ { ticker: 'GOOG', price: 206, ... },
           { ticker: 'AAPL', price: 47, ... },
           { ticker: 'MSFT', price: 39, ... },
           { ticker: 'GOOG', price: 159, ... },
           { ticker: 'MSFT', price: 39, ... },
           { ticker: 'MSFT', price: 21, ... },
           { ticker: 'GOOG', price: 80, ... },
           { ticker: 'AAPL', price: 20, ... },
           { ticker: 'AAPL', price: 73, ... },
           { ticker: 'MSFT', price: 49, ... },
           ... ];
```

I'd like to return a reduced array with, for each ticker, the object having the maximum price (and the other properties) in a functional way.

Here's is what I have so far:

```
c.reduce(function(acc, y) { 
  return acc
    .filter(function(x) { return x.ticker!=y.ticker })
    .concat(
      acc.filter(function(x) { return x.ticker==y.ticker })
        .concat([y])
        .reduce(function(u,v) { 
          return u.price > v.price ? u : v } ) /* predicate */
    )  
}, []);
```

But is there a more idiomatic JavaScript way of doing this?
Underscore and lodash are welcome but please no jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

With lodash:

```
var res = _(stocks)
    // group all elements by 'ticker'
    .groupBy(function (s) {
        return s.ticker;
    // sort each group by price descending and get the first element (the max)
    }).map(function (n) {
        return _(n).sortBy(n, function (v) {
            return -v.price;
        }).first();
    });

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
```

That code gives:

```
[
    {
        "ticker": "GOOG",
        "price": 206
    },
    {
        "ticker": "AAPL",
        "price": 73
    },
    {
        "ticker": "MSFT",
        "price": 49
    }
]
```

Shorter version sorting ASC and getting the last element:

```
var res = _(stocks)
    .groupBy('ticker')
    .map(function (n) {
        return _(n).sortBy('price').last();
    });
```

Comment: My apologies. Please try my code again, I referred to `x.stock` from a previous version instead of `x.ticker`. Thanks for your post!

Comment: Side note: I'd use `_.first()` instead of `(...)[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried solve this task with functional concept.

```
var stocks =
  [
   {ticker: 'GOOG', price: 206},
   {ticker: 'AAPL', price: 47},
   {ticker: 'MSFT', price: 39},
   {ticker: 'GOOG', price: 159},
   {ticker: 'MSFT', price: 39},
   {ticker: 'MSFT', price: 21},
   {ticker: 'GOOG', price: 80},
   {ticker: 'AAPL', price: 20},
   {ticker: 'AAPL', price: 73},
   {ticker: 'MSFT', price: 49}
 ];

var result = stocks.reduce(function (acc, next) {
  return acc
        .filter(function (stock) {
           return stock.ticker != next.ticker
        })
        .concat(acc.reduce(function (u, v) {
           return u.ticker == v.ticker && u.price < v.price ? v : u;
        }, next));
}, []);


console.log(result);
```

Output

```
[ 
 { ticker: 'GOOG', price: 206 },
 { ticker: 'AAPL', price: 73 },
 { ticker: 'MSFT', price: 49 } 
]
```

Comment: how different is that from my own solution?

Comment: There was a mistake. No? When I copied your code It gave me wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure JavaScript solution without any framework that uses only one `filter()` and one `reduce()`:

**Code**

```
var stocks = [ { ticker: 'GOOG', price: 206},
           { ticker: 'AAPL', price: 47},
           { ticker: 'MSFT', price: 39},
           { ticker: 'GOOG', price: 159},
           { ticker: 'MSFT', price: 39},
           { ticker: 'MSFT', price: 21},
           { ticker: 'GOOG', price: 80},
           { ticker: 'AAPL', price: 20},
           { ticker: 'AAPL', price: 73},
           { ticker: 'MSFT', price: 49}];

function max(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(item){
    return this[item.ticker] === item;
  }.bind(arr.reduce(function(res, cur) {
    return (res[cur.ticker] = (res[cur.ticker] 
        ? (res[cur.ticker].price > cur.price ? res[cur.ticker] : cur)
        : cur
    )), res;
  }, {})));
}

console.log(max(stocks));
```

**Result**

```
[ 
 { ticker: 'GOOG', price: 206 },
 { ticker: 'AAPL', price: 73 },
 { ticker: 'MSFT', price: 49 } 
]
```

**JSBin**

https://jsbin.com/linevudika/edit?js,console